# Both String look same but dont equal

Tags: java

i've same list internal and external comment list both list content look same but it dose not work. see the example below.

```
List<String> internalComment = Arrays.asList(
    "[~abhijit.karanjkar] [~aiyer][~pdewan]How can we test this if the LDAP configuration is set to false? Is it necessary this be set to false? If so why? Is there a workaround for testing?nnCurrently this would fail any meta plkayak tests in automation as well as manual test performed by webomates or in-house specific testing.");
List<String> externalComment = Arrays.asList(
    "[~abhijit.karanjkar] [~aiyer][~pdewan]How can we test this if the LDAP configuration is set to false? Is it necessary this be set to false? If so why? Is there a workaround for testing?nnCurrently this would fail any meta plkayak tests in automation as well as manual test performed by webomates or in-house specific testing.");

Set<String> newComment = new HashSet<>();
externalComment.forEach(extComm -> {
    if (!internalComment.contains(extComm)) {
        newComment.add(extComm);
    }
});
```

when i debug and found that one extra space is added which i highlighted as below : ***why one extra space is added and how to remove it?***

*internalComment*

[[, ~, a, b, h, i, j, i, t, ., k, a, r, a, n, j, k, a, r, ],  , [, ~, a, i, y, e, r, ***], [,*** ~, p, d, e, w, a, n, ], H, o, w,  , c, a, n,  , w, e,  , t, e, s, t,  , t, h, i, s,  , i, f,  , t, h, e,  , L, D, A, P,  , c, o, n, f, i, g, u, r, a, t, i, o, n,  , i, s,  , s, e, t,  , t, o,  , f, a, l, s, e, ?,  , I, s,  , i, t,  , n, e, c, e, s, s, a, r, y,  , t, h, i, s,  , b, e,  , s, e, t,  , t, o,  , f, a, l, s, e, ?,  , I, f,  , s, o,  , w, h, y, ?,  , I, s,  , t, h, e, r, e,  , a,  , w, o, r, k, a, r, o, u, n, d,  , f, o, r,  , t, e, s, t, i, n, g, ?, n, n, C, u, r, r, e, n, t, l, y,  , t, h, i, s,  , w, o, u, l, d,  , f, a, i, l,  , a, n, y,  , m, e, t, a,  , p, l, k, a, y, a, k,  , t, e, s, t, s,  , i, n,  , a, u, t, o, m, a, t, i, o, n,  , a, s,  , w, e, l, l,  , a, s,  , m, a, n, u, a, l,  , t, e, s, t,  , p, e, r, f, o, r, m, e, d,  , b, y,  , w, e, b, o, m, a, t, e, s,  , o, r,  , i, n, -, h, o, u, s, e,  , s, p, e, c, i, f, i, c,  , t, e, s, t, i, n, g, .]

***externalComment***

[[, ~, a, b, h, i, j, i, t, ., k, a, r, a, n, j, k, a, r, ],  , [, ~, a, i, y, e, r, ***], ‌, [,*** ~, p, d, e, w, a, n, ], H, o, w,  , c, a, n,  , w, e,  , t, e, s, t,  , t, h, i, s,  , i, f,  , t, h, e,  , L, D, A, P,  , c, o, n, f, i, g, u, r, a, t, i, o, n,  , i, s,  , s, e, t,  , t, o,  , f, a, l, s, e, ?,  , I, s,  , i, t,  , n, e, c, e, s, s, a, r, y,  , t, h, i, s,  , b, e,  , s, e, t,  , t, o,  , f, a, l, s, e, ?,  , I, f,  , s, o,  , w, h, y, ?,  , I, s,  , t, h, e, r, e,  , a,  , w, o, r, k, a, r, o, u, n, d,  , f, o, r,  , t, e, s, t, i, n, g, ?, n, n, C, u, r, r, e, n, t, l, y,  , t, h, i, s,  , w, o, u, l, d,  , f, a, i, l,  , a, n, y,  , m, e, t, a,  , p, l, k, a, y, a, k,  , t, e, s, t, s,  , i, n,  , a, u, t, o, m, a, t, i, o, n,  , a, s,  , w, e, l, l,  , a, s,  , m, a, n, u, a, l,  , t, e, s, t,  , p, e, r, f, o, r, m, e, d,  , b, y,  , w, e, b, o, m, a, t, e, s,  , o, r,  , i, n, -, h, o, u, s, e,  , s, p, e, c, i, f, i, c,  , t, e, s, t, i, n, g, .]

Comment: The `externalComment` has additional comma and space instead of just space

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've posted. I assume in your real code, the strings *aren't* coming from string literals, but data from elsewhere. That's where the problem is likely to lie, but as we don't know where the strings come from, it's hard to help further.

Comment: @Jon Skeet this is the sample code. the real string comes from json response of JIRA Rest API

Comment: It might be, for instance, a non-printable character or a zero-width character.

Comment: But the sample code doesn't show the problem. Fundamentally, the problem isn't with sets or lists - it's that you're receiving two different strings when you expect to receive the same string twice. That's what your question should focus on: did *both* strings come from the API, or is one from elsewhere? Why do you expect them to be the same? That sort of thing.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to compare the characters of the string, so you can find the difference?

Comment: both string come from the API

Comment: Convert characters to ints before printing. `externalComment` contains some non-printable character.

Comment: That example does not make sense as it shows like nothing related to the story.

Comment: I am just looking a way that newComment dose not get any previous comment which is defined in internalComment.

Comment: @AnasAnsari: And that works, if the data is as you expect it to be, but the data *isn't* as you expect it to be. So that's what you need to focus on - the list and set code is irrelevant. You have two strings that you expect to be equal, but which aren't equal. Focus *just* on that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your time. Now I'am just focusing on that.